# How to form post to two different php files using action?

Tags: php, html

So here's my code

```
<form class="form-signin" action="formProcess.php" action="Portal.php" action="Blog.php"    method="post">
```

but it seems to be only sending the form info to formProcess.php. I can tell because I am not able toto pull the form data on Portal.php. Here's my variables:

```
$sitename = $_POST['siteName'];
```

but I try to use it later down in the code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#"><? echo $sitename; ?></a>
```

and it does not display $sitename on my page.
We have tried using $test = ('hi'); and it echoes hi just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The first one attribute is used, the others of the same name are ignored.

If you need to put data in two different scripts (st. is wrong here, why you need that?), include `Portal.php` inside the processing of form data in `formProcess.php`.

Comment: What is st.? Also how do I include Portal.php?

Comment: @sebchiken: something. Including Portal.php you can make just as `include 'Portal.php'` but the problem is elsewhere. The problem is that you need to process form data in more scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple instances of the same attribute inside a html tag, having multiple action targets isn't suggested, and if you can join php scripts as `panther` suggested you should do it.

If however you cannot alter the php files and you prefer to retrieve data from each of them individually  you may call a javascript function that then calls your php scripts, as such:

```
<form action="javascript:callPHP()" action="formProcess.php">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function callPHP(){
   $.post( "formProcess.php", function( data ) {
       // handle data from formProcess.php
   });
   $.post( "Portal.php", function( data ) {
       // handle data from Portal.php
   });
   // etc
}
```